# Relationships in Views always 4 results also if no reference for the field

Tags: views

I have two content types :

- meals
- wine

In my content-type "**meals**" I have a entity reference to "**wine**".

Now I wanna create a views to show all **meals**, with a reference to **wine**.

I have create a views with following settings:

> ***FILTER CRITERIA***
>
> = Content Type (= meals)
>
> = (Content entity referenced from field_wine) Content: Published (Yes)
>
> ***RELATIONSHIPS***
>
> = Entity Reference: Wine

In my view I get all results for that. So if a wine was tagged in 2 meals, I get a view with that two meals.

My Problem now: I always wanna show 4 meals. So I want to show the 2 meals + 2 others.

If i have a wine with 1 meals. So i want so show the 1 meal + 3 others.. and so on.

Do any know how to fill the results if the missing some meals?

Comment: So the "others" meals don't have wine, they have, for example, coke?

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more.It seems like some information is missing Which is creating ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do via https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view . So, below is the steps:-

1. Create a view for the meal which shows all meals and add one more field "nid" as a hidden parameter(just tick exclude from display) so that we will have an available token for nid.
2. Now, create another block of wine and pass meal's nid as a contextual fitler. so, it will give you all wine as per single meals.
3. The next step do the trick. Go back to block #1(meal's view) and and add global:view field and pass "[nid]" of the meal as a contextual filter in that field(you will find an option don't worry) and select the view and display of the #2(wine's block).
4. That's it, here you have all the meals with wines. :)

Hope it will solve your problem.